# JavaScript Validation on Time Field (0:00 format not accepted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Here is my code for validating incorrect time formats:

```
 $('.allts').delegate(".tf", "focusout", function (e)
        {
                var curval = this.value;
                curval = curval.replace(';', ':');
                curval = curval.replace(" ", ':');
                curval = curval.replace('.', ':');                
                //alert(curval);
                if (/^\d$/.test(curval))
                {
                        curval = "0" + curval + ":00";
                }
                if (/^[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test(curval))
                        {
                                curval = "0" + curval;
                        }
                if (curval >= 10 && curval <= 12)
                {
                        curval = curval + ":00";
                }
                if(curval.length==2&&curval >= 0 && curval <= 12){
                curval = curval + ":00";
                }
                this.value = curval;
                if (this.value != "")
                {
                        if (!isValidDate(curval))
                        {
                                this.style.background = "#faa";
                                $('#msg_tformat').html('Please enter a valid time').show();
                                this.value = "";  
                        }
```

My requirement is not to accept the 0:00 time format. If I give time formats like 0:00 it should display an error message like: "Please enter a valid time". Can anyone suggest the 
proper way to validate for this in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (curval === '0:00') ...`?

Answer (score 0):

add to the `isValidDate` function something like this:

```
if( curval === '0:00' || curval === '00:00' ) {
  return false;
}
```